# Newbie - how to get FB publish_status permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, publish-actions

UGH,

So we have applied for FB developer - which was easily granted - and we created a FB application on the FB developer site.

We'll be using PHP and did manage to get the login (using FB) to work, but what we want to allow people to post directly to their FB account using our application.

It seems that one needs to use "publish_actions" during the FB login to do that.  Currently our app does not have these permissions.

We see where you need to go through some process to get "approved", but that process seems to want to "see" how you use it.  How can they see how we'll use it without us having permissions TO USE IT?

What are we missing here?  How do we get started to test our application - without having permission to write????

Any insights or pointers would be appreciated.

BTW - we've developed great applications using the Twitter API that have been running flawlessly for over a year - never ran into such a brick wall.

Thanks,

Len

Comment: Admins, developers and testers you can ask for that permission without it being approved by Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

The first comment by WizKid is the correct answer for this question. Anyone listed under the Roles tab of your Application Dashboard will be able to grant "public_action" or any other permission without going through the App Review process. This tab is https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID]/roles/ (replace [APP_ID] with your actual application ID).

Comment: yup, we figured it out after we posted this...  thanks!